# Xcode 6 Instruments freeze

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, instruments

Profiling my iOS 8 app in Xcode 6 Instruments will run the app for about 5 seconds and then freeze. The profiler will still run after that point but the app is frozen and unusable. Happens on device and simulator and regardless of which profiler I'm using (timer, leaks, etc.)

Running the app from the debugger or an ad hoc build works fine. Profiling with iOS 7 works fine as well.

Any idea why this may be happening? Is Instruments broken?

Comment: If you're having an issue, I'd suggest filing a bug report.

Comment: I am having the same issue, has anybody found any solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same issue here:

[Application hangs when profiling with instrument in XCode 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390000/application-hangs-when-profiling-with-instrument-in-xcode-6-0-1)

Looks like if you remove all the NSLog statements it will fix it. 
For me this is happening only on iOS 8, i have no problems on iOS 7.

Comment: This seemed to work in a small test case. Unfortunately, seems like the logger in one of the libraries I'm using is still freezing instruments, regardless of whether or not the logger is 'on'. This is still the best answer +1.

Comment: For reference you can use this `#define NSLog(...) do { } while (0)`

Comment: Another solution will be to start the instruments recording after your app is started. I had a bunch of methods in the code that when were running they were freezing the app, I've attached Instruments at the running app and started the recording after those methods finished, in this case you can also have Debug and Instruments at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

This was also happening to me on an iPod Touch + iOS 8.

Upgrading to 8.0.2 solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me I found out that Instruments was freezing when I started recording due to Xcode already running the application.

It's important for Xcode not to be running any processes when starting Instruments. If you do, Instruments will look like it is hanging.

You can push through the hang by going to Xcode and pressing "Continue Program Execution" on the bottom console toolbar of Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have a very large library that I work on and instruments hangs for me when trying to profile it. I found that I have to have `DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT` set to `DWARF with dSYM File` at the app's build settings level.