# Application hangs when profiling with instrument in Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, instruments

I am observing that whenever I am profiling my application using instrument in Xcode 6.0.1, application hangs every time while I am browsing through the application. I am using iPhone 5S (iOS 8.0.2) to run my application. When I run the application on device it runs all fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the fix - disabling the NSLog statements (profiling on release and not on debug) solved the issue for me.

Comment: Getting the same issue with the latest Xcode and Insturments on and iPad air and the same thing is happening to me event when I profile on release

Comment: Scratch that removed NSLog from the entire app and now it works :-/ FFS Apple why?

Comment: How in the world did you figure this out?  Thank you!

Comment: @Steve Please see my solution above

Comment: @Abhinav how did you find this solution? I'm very curious

Comment: @ReyGonzales I actually helped one of my QA team member in fixing an automation tool bug where the tool was hanging when a heavy statement was being logged in the console. This triggered me to try out the same thing here which thankfully worked.

Answer (score 2):

Extending on Abhinav's correct answer, NSLog() is indeed triggering the issue, but not all NSLogs, only some very large ones. In my case I was logging some long responses from a web service, and commenting only those ones out fixed the problem of Instruments hanging. I guess this is the reason why the issue is not as widespread as you'd think (I couldn't find any reference to it on Apple's dev forums).

Answer (score 1):

I've just been solving the same issue and it turned out to be caused by something else. I'm not 100% sure yet which part of my code is responsible, but it's got something to do with accessing the internet. So I've switched into Airplane mode et voila!
So my conclusion is that a network request was hanging the main thread (only when running Instruments tho -- weird) and if anyone else is running into similar problems, try finding what might hang your main thread.

Hope it saves some time :)

Z.

Answer (score 1):

### Follow those steps:

1. **Run** app on your device. It would be better if you set *Release* build in *Edit scheme* menu.
2. Go to the **Debug navigator** section on your *Navigator* (left menu in Xcode).
3. Click on **CPU**.
4. Click on **Profile in Instruments** and choose **Transfer**.
5. Instruments will run *Time Profiler*. Then in top panel click on **Library** button (looks like "+").
6. The library menu will open. You need to select your instrument.