# Iphone 5 Appium and jUnit - App did not have elements

Tags: ios, iphone, junit, appium

I have a problem with my automated tests on iPhone 5. I could previously start test on iPad with iOS 6.1 but now I would like to do it on iPhone 5 iOS 8.1

In eclipse I got message A new session could not be created.

Log from appium:

```
error: Failed to start an Appium session, err was: Error: App did not have     elements
info: [debug] Error: App did not have elements
at     /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/    ios.js:459:30
at Object.cb [as callback]     (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios    /ios-controller.js:247:7)
at next (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:801:43)
at /Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16
at exports.respond (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/common.js:28:9)
at null.<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/lib/devices/ios/ios.js:1449:18)
at getResultAndSendNext (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/lib/command-proxy.js:146:20)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/lib/command-proxy.js:88:7)
at Socket.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:944:16
```

info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":33,"value":{"message":"A new session could not be created. (Original error: App did not have elements)","origValue":"App did not have elements"},"sessionId":null}
info: <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 29025.843 ms - 172

capabilities:

```
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 5 iOS 8.1");
capabilities.setCapability("udid","104ce995950282f9dfaf371bf05ee6b00e7c0027);
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Beginning iOS 8, excessive amount of **NSLog** outputs can create deadlock in the internal communication of UIAutomation and Appium server. (*read this article for more info [Appium's Github page](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4032)*)

This causes such undesired outcomes.

A preventive workaround is described [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26743671/2311375): which solved the issue on my case. I hope it will help.

Comment: Yes. In my case I had log from iPhone simulator displaying option enabled, and that was the reason of error.